# How to override the getter method of a super class's private property

Tags: ios, objective-c

Usually, we can use the following code to set a getter method for a property.

```
- (UIButton *)aButton {
    if (!_aButton) {
        _aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    }
    return _aButton;
}
```

Now, the property is declared in the super class's `.m` file.
So.
**Question:** How to do that in a sub class?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `valueForKey` `performSelector`, `swizzling`? What else have you tried?

Comment: The whole point of a property being private is so that subclasses *can't* override it. Don't try. Your code will break when the implementation of the superclass changes.

Comment: @rmaddy yeah, I know it. I was thinking if there is any possibility I could do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply declare the existence of private methods in a superclass in a category header, then use them.  You cannot assign a private instance variable from the superclass directly, other than using setValue:forKey: or other runtime functions like object_setIvar().

```
@interface Superclass (PrivateDecls)
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *aButton;
@end

@implementation Subclass
...
- (UIButton *)aButton {
    UIButton *button = [super aButton];
    if (!button) {
        button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [super setAButton:button];
    }
    return button;
}
@end
```

However, normally such properties are privately declared for a reason.  They are subject to change with each release, etc., and your code could easily break in the future.  Even if just your own classes, a programmer changing the code in the superclass may not be aware that there is another class in the project overriding it, and could easily make a breaking change.

Normally the only reason to do stuff like this is for unit tests, temporary debugging code, or for two closely related classes where just the other class should know about the private/package private methods, and not any other class -- otherwise the superclass should simply declare them in the public header.  Even in this latter situation, it may make sense to make a "SuperclassPrivate.h" or "SuperclassProtected.h" header to declare methods/properties used by other related classes (such as UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h) so that certain other classes can import that header, while not being public for general use.  If you do go this route, it may be best to add comments in the superclass to point out there is another class overriding the property in question.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.